# How to justify text in a table's cell in LyX?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, lyx

I'd like to justify the text that is in the cell of a table (as I would and could in the main body of the text).

However, when I right-click > alignment, the only possible options are Left, Right, Center, Decimal.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the table settings instead, where you have set the width of the column. There you can select *Justified* from the *Horizontal alignment* drop down.

[image: LyX table settings]

Comment: Note that the "Justified" option is absent until you specify some width. (This is probably why I had missed this option previously.)